# Preview is not showing in android studio version 3.2

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

I am getting this error messages after i update the studio and modify the design gradle version 28.0.0.

I don't know what is wrong.
[image]

Help will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Try File->Invalidate caches and Restart to restart android studio

Comment: I tried but failed.
Any other suggestions?

Comment: delete .gradle folder , build folder and resync project

Comment: You can also try to remove these @string references then sync gradle

Answer (score 3):

This is a issue that occurs time to time.
Here's how you fix it:-

1. Clean Project **(Build->Clean Project)**
2. Invalidate and restart **(File-> Invalidate Caches / Restart)**
3. After restarting sync the project manually by clicking on the sync button[image: Third button from the left]

Third button from the left

Comment: I tried every step you mention.And also delete the .idea folder and make the project and rebuild it. but nothing is helping me out.

Comment: Now rebuild the project. It that doesn't work then try restrating

Answer (score 0):

First of all check your XML is there any error resolve that.

then

1.Build-> Clean Project. 
2.Build-> Rebuild Project.
3. After that go to file menu -> Invalidate Caches/Restart.
4. File -> Sync Project with Gradle files.

Answer (score 0):

Resolve the errors then try:

- Build-Rebuild Project
- Build-Clean Project
- File-Sync Project with *Gradle* files (sync over the internet).